# Leaving Canada “unvaccinated”

Tags: canada, one-way, vaccinations

Can I leave Canada on a one-way ticket if I’m “unvaccinated”? (had an adverse reaction after shot #1 so don’t want to get another).

I could leave on a foreign passport  (different from the destination country) but I am a Canadian citizen as well, and am also a permanent resident in the country of destination.

I know that technically at the moment they will only let out “unvaccinated foreign nationals who do not permanently reside in Canada.” We will be relocating permanently out of Canada, so I’m wondering if I would qualify under this definition to be able to leave?

Comment: Did you ask for a doctors declaration about your adverse reaction to the shot? In some/many countries that will be accepted as a good reason not to be fully vaccinated.

Comment: Further to @Willeke's point, see the section "Medical Inability to be Vaccinated" on [this page.](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/domestic-travel)

Comment: You could also go to the U.S. by car and take a flight there.

Comment: Well, the purpose of a vaccine is to train your immune system to fight the live virus. **It is normal to have the symptoms of a miniature version of the illness**.  That said, a few people do have *unexpected, different* reactions (e.g. to an adjuvant derived from a plant you're allergic to), and the 2-shot viruses use a fairly new technology.  If so, the J&J vaccine might be an option, as it uses traditional vaccine tech.  And it's a "1 and done".

Comment: @xngtng: Unless they are a US citizen or permanent resident, they will need to be vaccinated to enter the US by car.

Comment: Is the trip you're asking about the trip during which you will be moving from Canada to your new country of residence?

Answer (score 6):

The specific statement is:

**[Foreign nationals who don’t qualify as fully vaccinated and who don’t permanently reside in Canada will be allowed to depart Canada up until August 31, 2022.They must show proof of a valid COVID-19 test result at the time of boarding.](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/domestic-travel)**

In the [Immigration and Citizenship Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/i-2.5/page-1.html)

> foreign national means a person who is not a Canadian citizen or a permanent resident.

You are unfortunately not going to be able to board a flight legally whatever passport you travel with, and attempting deception is likely to have serious consequences.

Your options are:

1. Get your second shot and wait 14 days
2. Get a valid medical exemption
3. Depart by land to the US and fly from there. However unless you are a US national or permanent resident [you will need proof of vaccination for entry to the US.](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2021/10/29/fact-sheet-guidance-travelers-enter-us-land-ports-entry-and-ferry-terminals)

Comment: As of this date, there are [no vaccination requirements](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html) and [no test requirements](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html) for travelers entering the US via land or sea.  (On each page, scroll down to the "Overview" section, where it is explained that vaccination & test requirements only apply to travelers arriving by air.)

Comment: @MichealSeifert, The pages you reference are only about air travel. [For the land border there is this](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2021/10/29/fact-sheet-guidance-travelers-enter-us-land-ports-entry-and-ferry-terminals).

Comment: Its also likely that either the US or Canada will drop their vaxx passport program very soon as the world transitions to "living with COVID". The US will drop masks on planes on April 18th, vaxx checks will likely follow soon after.

Comment: We can only pray that they actually drop the requirement instead of extending it once again, @JonathanReez